# Moment.JS: Convert date

Tags: date, momentjs

I have this **moment** date: `2015-10-30T12:00:00.645Z`

I want to convert to this string: `20151030T120000Z`with **moment.js**.

How can I do this?

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var date = '2015-10-30T12:00:00.645Z';
var dateMoment = moment.utc(date).format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmss') + 'Z';
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hazkzrdq/2/)**